# discretization function throwing sudden error

Tags: r

i am using R 3.6.1. I want to discretize the continuous variable. I tried using discretize function as in https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/arules/versions/1.6-4/topics/discretize . But it throws error.

```
library(infotheo)
data(iris)
x <- iris[,1]
table(discretize(x, breaks = 3))
Error in discretize(x, breaks = 3) : unused argument (breaks = 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You load to the wrong package. The function you are referring to is from `arules`:

```
library(infotheo)
library(arules)

x <- iris[,1]
table(arules::discretize(x, breaks = 3)) #works
table(infotheo::discretize(x, breaks = 3)) # does not have a breaks argument
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using `infotheo::discretize`, which has no `breaks` argument. Here are the parameters given by the documentation:

```r
# library(infotheo)
discretize( X, disc="equalfreq", nbins=NROW(X)^(1/3) )
```

The package you link to is `arules`, and `arules::discretize` does have a `breaks` argument:

```r
# library(arules)
discretize(x, method = "frequency", breaks = 3, 
  labels = NULL, include.lowest = TRUE, right = FALSE, dig.lab = 3,
  ordered_result = FALSE, infinity = FALSE, onlycuts = FALSE, 
  categories, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

in R there are many libraries, you are trying to use **discretize** function from **arules** package. If you loaded both packages:

```
library(infotheo)
library(arules)
data(iris)
x <- iris[,1]
table(arules::discretize(x, breaks = 3))
```

or

```
table(infotheo::discretize(x, nbins = 3))
```